# Ordinary Differential equations solutions unique or not.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we solve Ordinary differential equations,  we put a constant integrating factor C.
So my questions are- 
1.which side does this factor be placed and in which format. ?
2. Do ODEs have unique solutions or we can have different solutions for the same question ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is a "side" in an ODE or its solution in a context-free sense? What is the "format" of a constant? What is ODE in 2., is there an IVP connected? Do you understand the conditions and claim of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem?